# How to avail GCP OS login feature on non google provided images

Tags: ssh, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, pam, google-migrate-for-compute-engine

I have migrated few workloads from AWS to GCP , now trying to enable OS login feature on that migrated  workloads.

Since it is not a native google image , Hence we need to build os login package on this migrated image .

There is a github resource about this https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/guest-oslogin

but couldn't able to enable it .

If anyone have done this already , please advise .

Comment: Which Linux distribution are you using? How were the instances migrated?

Comment: Debian 9 and RHEL 7

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/managing-instance-access) it's more detailed then guide at github. If you already have SSH keys you can [import](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/managing-instance-access#add_oslogin_keys) them. In case if something goes wrong you can use [serial port connection](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/viewing-serial-port-output) for access to your VMs with existing login and password.

Provide more details about your steps during migration from AWS to GCP and issues with OS login configuration.

**EDIT** It's easier to migrate VMs from  AWS into Compute Engine if you use [Google Cloud Migrate for Compute Engine](https://cloud.google.com/migrate/compute-engine/docs/4.8) (formerly Velostrata).